# Посоветуйте книгу по Postgre SQL ver > 8.x

Tags: книги, postgresql

Собственно сабж. Ну конечно, кроме офф. документации.
Прошу не пинать ведь думаю многим пригодится...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например:

- [PostgreSQL 9.0 High Performance](http://www.wowebook.be/book/postgresql-9-0-high-performance/);
- [PostgreSQL 9 Administration Cookbook](http://www.wowebook.be/book/postgresql-9-administration-cookbook/);
- [PostgreSQL: Up and Running](http://www.wowebook.be/book/postgresql-up-and-running/).

Answer (score 1):

- Увы, все без исключения книги отстают от англоязычного руководства как минимум на годы
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/
  Оно очень неплохое.
- Ещё есть раздел на sql.ru там свои  FAQ, туда даже некоторые разработчики заглядывают
- Есть описание на вики http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL
     Там я сделал раздел по убойным фишкам для каждой версии, начиная от 8.3
- Общая книга по SQL http://www.sql.ru/docs/sql/u_sql/